# Where to start to get collected data viewed?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

There is server ASP.NET Core application which collects data from various sources. It stores that data on Azure.
I need to enable user to look at that data before storing. To make it sure that data are correct.
How and where to start? I suppose that I need to make new controller and view.